# How to Quantify the Race Condition. Suppose I have 20 threads in a program and 10 times the race condition has came

Tags: multithreading, race-condition

How to Quantify the Race Condition. Suppose I have 20 threads in a program and 10 times the race condition has came.

Supoose I want to make a general formula for the same what it may be.

Answer (score 0):

The race condition happens once for every two threads; therefore  RC(n) = n/2. qed :)